# Modify the android.toolchain.cmake to reduce the package size

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

When I compiled the Android release package, I removed **-g** from **ANDROID_COMPILER_FLAGS** in the **android.toolchain.cmake** file of ndk, and then I found that the package size became smaller, and it reduced the **.eh_frame** section.

I thought the release package would not be affected by -g?
Is my approach correct?
What is the reason for its reduction?
Or is there any other way to achieve the same effect, because I feel that it is not safe to directly modify the ndk file. (I've added -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-unwind-tables)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to remove `-g`. `-g` produces debugging information (see [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options) options). This debug info requires much space. But according to [this](https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/243) post the debug info is removed (stripped from the executable) when creating a release apk.

Comment: In fact, no, the size of the release package compiled with the `-g0` parameter is different from the release package compiled without any operations, so it does not remove all the effects of `-g` when compiling the release package . But thank you anyway.